# Parsing JavaScript using Perl: getting "undef" from JE->parse

Tags: javascript, perl, parsing, static-code-analysis

I have Javascript code and I need to parse javascript variables into perl hash. Is there any ready-to-use module? I tried [JE::parse()](https://metacpan.org/pod/JE#$j-%3Eparse(-$code,-$filename,-$first_line_no-)) and [JavaScript::HashRef::Decode](https://metacpan.org/pod/JavaScript::HashRef::Decode) but neither worked.

Expected behaviour:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use SomeModule::ParseJSVariables qw/decode_js/;

my $str = qq/
var data = {
    'abc': 1,
    'def' : 2
    'xyz' : { 'foo' : 'bar' }
}
/;

my $res = decode_js($str);
warn Dumper $res; #

# expected result: 
# { 
#   name => 'data', 
#   value => {
#     'abc' => 1,
#     'def' => 2
#     'xyz' => { 'foo' => 'bar' }
#     }
# }


use JE;
my $j = new JE;
my $parsed = $j->parse($str);
warn Dumper $parsed; # undef :(
```

If there are no ready-to-use modules, I will be glad if someone suggest right regexp or parsing approach.

UPD, clarification. I have ~ thousand lines of javascript code and I need only get content of variables which are explicitly given in global scope, like var x = { 'foo' : 'bar' }. Other code can be skipped from parsing.

My environment :

```
$ perl --version

This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ uname -r
4.19.24-041924-generic
```

Comment: Questions about 3rd party code or off site resources are off Topic on Stack Overflow. Check  [Where can I ask about “finding a tool, library, or favorite off-site resource?”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251134/387194)

Comment: Can you give more context / input examples ? Do you only need to parse (maybe slightly relaxed) JSON, or full Javascript code (with loops and functions and all that)?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. For example, what would `decode_js` return when given the code `let a = console.log("hi"), b = a, c = { foo: function (i) { return function () { return i++; }; }(0) }; { let b = 42; console.log(Math.sqrt(b)); }`?

Comment: Why did `JE::parse` not work?

Comment: @jcubic Imho it's not off topic. There are a lot of questions about 3rd party libraries on stackoverflow, moreover I added question that if no ready-to-use 3rd party code I'll be glad for suggesting regexp or parsing approach

Comment: @Thilo, yes, I need to parse only variables so slightly relaxed JSON is enought.

Comment: @melpomene, please check previous answer, I need to parse only variables for now.

Comment: Please answer my question. "*I need to parse only variables*" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @Thilo firstly I can't install JE::parse without skipping tests. And even if I skip tests and install it I got `undef` as result

Comment: @melpomene, I have ~ thousand lines of javascript code and I need only get content of variables which are explicitly given in global scope, like `var x = { 'foo' : 'bar' }`. Other code can be skipped.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What result do you expect from the sample input I gave above?

Comment: Would you please add a minimal, runnable example of the JE code that doesn't behave as you expect?  Also, what OS and Perl version?  I see JE is known to break on ActiveState 32-bit.

Comment: @melpomene I expect empty string from this code since `let` declares a block scope local variable, but I need only variables from global scope.

Comment: @PaulSerikov OK. What results do you expect from the same code, but with `let` changed to `var`?

Comment: @cxw added into body of question.

Comment: @melpomene same, nothing. Value of `'foo'` property is function, in my case object which has at least one "dynamic" property must be skipped fully (however for future cases option to skip just dynamic values will be useful ). `var b = 42` not in global scope, so it must be skipped too. And finally `var a = console.log("hi"), b = a` needs to be skipped too, because it's also dynamic.

Comment: OK, so `var x; x = 42;` should also return nothing, right?

Comment: Yes. I need only those variables which are declared as object immediately after definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out simplest solution :)

The key idea is to execute javascript code in new context using [JavaScript::V8](https://metacpan.org/pod/JavaScript::V8) or [JavaScript::Any](https://metacpan.org/pod/JavaScript::Any) and mock `console.log` function.

```
my $str = qq/
var data = {
    'abc': 1,
    'def' : 2,
    'xyz' : { 'foo' : 'bar' }
};
/;

use Data::Dumper;
use JavaScript::V8;

sub extract_js_glob_var {
    my ( $code, $var_name ) = @_;
    my $res;
    my $context = JavaScript::V8::Context->new();
    $context->eval($str);
    $context->bind( console_log => sub { $res = @_[0] } );
    $context->eval('console_log('.$var_name.')');
    undef $context;
    return $res;
}

warn Dumper extract_js_glob_var($str, 'data');  # 'data.xyz' is also supported ;)
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, I have good news and bad news, and they are the same news :) .  Your JS has a syntax error, and so JE returns `undef` per [the JE docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/JE#$j-%3Eparse(-$code,-$filename,-$first_line_no-)).  Specifically, there is a `,` missing on the `def` line.  The following test works for me:

Code:

```
use Data::Dumper;

# Note: use q[ ] instead of qq/ /.  q instead of qq so Perl doesn't interpolate
# into the contents, and [ ] instead of / / so that JS comments can appear
# in the block.
my $str = q[
var data = {
    'abc': 1,
    'def' : 2,   // <==== There was a comma missing here!
    'xyz' : { 'foo' : 'bar' }
}
];

use JE;
my $j = new JE;
my $parsed = $j->parse($str);
warn Dumper $parsed;
```

Output: too big to show here :) .  But it does include what you want!

#### Extracting the output

This is going to be a bit of a challenge.  Hopefully the following will get you started.

Code:

```
use Data::Dumper::Compact 'ddc';   # <== for briefer output
use JE;

# Note: use q[ ] instead of qq/ /.  q instead of qq so Perl doesn't interpolate
# into the contents, and [ ] instead of / / so that JS comments can appear
# in the block.
my $str = q[
var data = {
    'abc': 1,
    'def' : 2,   // <==== There was a comma missing here!
    'xyz' : { 'foo' : 'bar' }
}
];

my $j = new JE;
my $parsed = $j->parse($str);
print ddc $parsed->{tree};     # <== {tree} holds the parsed source
```

Output (annotated):

```
bless( [
  [
    0,
    118,
  ],
  "statements",
  bless( [
    [
      1,
      118,
    ],
    "var",
    [
      "data",
      bless( [
        [
          12,
          117,
        ],
        "hash",    <== here's where your hash starts
        "abc",     <== 'abc': 1
        1,
        "def",     <== 'def': 2
        2,
        "xyz",     <== 'xyz': nested hash
        bless( [
          [
            98,
            115,
          ],
          "hash",
          "foo",
          "sbar",
        ], 'JE::Code::Expression' ),
      ], 'JE::Code::Expression' ),
    ],
  ], 'JE::Code::Statement' ),
], 'JE::Code::Statement' )
```